# Parsing a file with an unknown data format

Tags: json, parsing, serialization, format

I have to parse a file but I'm not sure which data format this file has. I also don't know if it's a proprietary protocol or commonly used so I ask it here before I start writing a parser for it myself. Below there is an excerpt of the file.

```
Persistent_Storage = {
    "0, 07/13/07 23:57:26, 1,20808,53, 38, Orc, Hunter, Dustwallow Marsh, , 0", -- [1]
    "0, 07/13/07 23:57:26, 1,49719,79, 30, Orc, Warlock, Orgrimmar, , 0", -- [2]
    ... more data ...
}
RoundInfo = {
    "0, 1, 13, 41", -- [1]
    "0, 2, 4, 33", -- [2]
    "0, 3, 6, 33", -- [3]
    ... more data ...
}
```

For the curious: this are game traces from the World of Warcraft Avatar History Dataset (http://mmnet.iis.sinica.edu.tw/dl/wowah/).

Comment: This isn't a development question. Regarding an "answer" it does appear to be somewhat containerized and comma delimited.

Comment: The link you posted has exact details of the fields and their meaning.

Comment: @Tim I know the meaning of the fields but I'm wondering whether there are some libraries that can parse this file and such what the name of this data format is.

Comment: The generalized format is comma separated values (CSV), but the specifics look to be completely proprietary. There are a number of good CSV parsing libraries available, I have used several over the years.

Comment: That's (probably) a Lua program which creates the arrays. So you could just use Lua to read it.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the paper available at the linked site

- **World of Warcraft Avatar History Dataset**
  http://mmnet.iis.sinica.edu.tw/pub/lee11_wowah.pdf

> **Data Collection Methodology** To collect the trace, we created a character in a World of
>   Warcraft realm (the Light’s Hope realm in Taiwan) and kept
>   it online throughout the 3-year study period. The character
>   was controlled by a program written in the **Lua** scripting
>   language, which World of Warcraft uses for interface
>   customization. Our program automatically collected a list of
>   the online avatars every 10 minutes.
>
> **Log Format** A log file is composed of two arrays: **Persistant_Storage**
>   and **RoundInfo**.  All the information collected about the
>   avatars’ history is stored in the Persistant_Storage array.
>   Each element stores the information about an avatar observed 
>   during the sampling period; thus, the number of elements is equal 
>   to the number of avatars online in that sampling interval. 
>   An element is a string that contains 11 fields separated by commas. 
>   The 11 fields are dummy, query time, query sequence number,
>   avatar ID, guild, level, race, class, zone, dummy, dummy.

The paper doesn't explicitly say these are Lua array literals but they do match the [Lua table constructor](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9) syntax.